# json array elements to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

```
 $cuisines = RestaurantProfile::select('cuisines')->get();
    $cuisines_array = array();
    foreach ($cuisines as $cuisine) {
        $string = implode(",",json_decode($cuisine, true));
        $array = explode(",", $string);
        foreach ($array as $single) {
             if (!in_array($single, $cuisines_array)) {
                 $cuisines_array[] = $single;
             }
         } 
    }
    dd($cuisines_array);
```

I want $cuisines_array to have something like

```
array:33 [▼
0 => "Afghani"
  1 => "Mughlai"
  2 => "Chinese"
  3 => "Indian"
  4 => "continental"
  5 => "south indian"
  6 => "mughlai"
```

But I am getting as in the screenshot: [output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Ch6.png)

My Cuisines attribute in table is [database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzORk.png).
Any leads?

Comment: you could just remove the braces, then explode and put them inside the array, no need to check in array, you could just use array unique in the end

Comment: Thanks your reply worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_slice()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) :

```
...
foreach (array_slice($array, 0, 6) as $single) {
...
```

---

```
array_slice()
```

> returns the sequence of elements from the array array as specified by
>   the offset and length parameters